# Transform pipeline separated string to a JSON object in Java

Tags: java, json, csv, transformation, smooks

In my Java program, I have pipeline separated string "value1|value2|value3|value4". I would like to convert that string to a JSON object in java like the following:

{ 
 “ payload” : 
    {
        "field1": value1,
        "field2": value2,
        "field3": value3,
        "field4": value4
    }
}

And I would like to read field1, field2, field3, field4 from a configuration file. 
Is it possible to do that transformation with Smooks or with any other library ?

Comment: While it is possible, why on earth the extra "rediction"? Why do you need the "payload" at all here?

Comment: It is not clear what you are talking about when you say "JSON object". JSON is not an object class, it is a data _serialization format_. Do you mean: You want to print your data structure (the nested hashtables) using JSON?

Comment: @hagello, in my java program, I want to convert the string "value1|value2|value3|value4" to json string  "{ “ payload” : { "field1": value1, "field2": value2, "field3": value3, "field4": value4 } }". I want to read the field value mappings from a configuration file and I want to use a third party library to do that transformation.

Comment: @fge, let's forget about the "payload" for the moment. I mean, let's say that I don't need the "payload" here. How can I do the transformation which I'm asking in my question ?

Comment: @hagello, are there still unclear points in my question ?

Comment: Could you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: Why do you need a third party library.  With String.split and System.out.printf You can do it in two lines (assuming you already read the field values from the config file.)

Comment: If you really want a third party library you are probably looking for a template engine like Apache Velocity